# remove items from array lists comparing item from another array list

Tags: java

I have the following classes in a java package

```
public class Pallet { ArrayList Cartons = new ArrayList(); }
public class Carton { Deliverydoc doc; }
public class Deliverydoc { String id; }
```

`main.java` within the package has the following array lists:

```
ArrayList<Pallet> Pallets = new ArrayList<Pallet>();
ArrayList<Carton> Cartons = new ArrayList<Carton>();
ArrayList<Deliverydoc> Deliverydocs = new ArrayList<Deliverydoc>();
```

Now, the question to you: Let's assume I got 3 items in Pallets & 3 in Cartons array lists, 2 items in Deliverydocs array list.
I have to match each "id" in Deliverydocs array list with Cartons array list and if Cartons array doesn't contains, delete the item from Cartons array list.
And for some items in Deliverydocs array list for no match in Pallets array list, I got to delete the pallet item so cartons item within it will also be deleted automatically.

I have resolved this myself but by declaring 2 more array lists but I don't want to declare additional array lists to achieve this reqmt..any other neat way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 then you have the `removeIf` method of `Collection`:

```
cartons.removeIf(carton -> deliverDocs.noneMatch(doc -> doc.id.equals(carton.doc.id)));
```

I don't really understand your requirements for deleting pallets as it is poorly worded. If it is 'similarly delete cartons inside pallets and then delete pallets with no cartons' then:

```
pallets.forEach(pallet -> pallet.cartons.removeIf(/* as above */));
pallets.removeIf(pallet -> pallet.cartons.isEmpty());
```

As an aside, you are using an unorthodox style of naming convention and formatting. It's worth researching and using standard conventions if you are planning to post questions on SO as they make things easier for readers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats easier if it was java 8. I am in java 6 and should have mentioned that before itself. Can you please let me know how this can be handled in java 6? thx - andy

Comment: For the poor wording on pallets, here you go. It's the similar case as cartons for pallets.